# Why is my duplicate removal script not capturing unique values

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to removal duplicates from a sorted list.

I wrote this script.

```
for(var i = 0; i < duplicateAuthors.length - 1; i++){
        if(duplicateAuthors[i] == duplicateAuthors[i + 1]) { continue; } 
        else{
            uniqAuthors.push(duplicateAuthors[i]);
        }
}
```

It works except it does not capture unique values in the list. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please post a complete code example so that we can reproduce the issue.

Comment: Note that if entries 5 and 6 in the list are the same, but 6 and 7 are not, your loop will treat the value of entry 6 as if it's unique.

Comment: Do you really have multiple references to the same object in the array, or do you have multiple objects that look like one another in the array (same property values, but different objects)?  If the latter, you'll have to compare a unique property on the object, since object's compare by reference.

Comment: It's all strings and there are multiple strings that have the same value. It is not the latter.

Comment: The rest of the code has been added.

Comment: edited again, missed some copy paste before.

Comment: OK, and now you wonder why, of the authors that appear multiple times in the list, the authors that appear only once are not output?

Comment: Yeah, there shouldn't be uniques in the list in the first place.

Comment: I thought that the _problem_ was that there weren't any unique values in the list.

Comment: I'm confused about what it is you're trying to achieve. Perhaps you can sum up what it is you're looking for in one statement.

Comment: It seems like you're looking for unique entries in an array that was explicitly created to only contains duplicates. You're not finding them because they're not there. Right?

Comment: Make sense you're confused, the additional code makes my intial question confusing. I'll just remove the additions and focus on the initial question asked.

Comment: I don't think that's a good idea, but ok. The rest of your code gave insight into the problem. By only focusing on this block of code, any answer you get is only going to be putting a band-aid on a larger problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var uniqAuthors = [];

for(var i = 0; i < duplicateAuthors.length; i++){
        if(uniqAuthors.indexOf(duplicateAuthors[i]) == -1) {
            uniqAuthors.push(duplicateAuthors[i]);
        }
}
```

The above code checks whether an object exist in an array or not, if not add it to array. Hence, at the end we will have an array of unique values.

Comment: This is more computationally expensive than the approach that the OP is (unsuccessfully) attempting. Also, it's not considered beneficial to post answers that contain nothing but code.

Comment: @Pointy - Thanks for advise. Actually, I normally post my answer and then  update with logic/comments. I had been writing code like above only to check for duplicates, it will be great if you post your performance oriented solution.

Comment: well the thing is that if the list is sorted, all the duplicates will be clumped together, so you can avoid searches like in your solution (which will of course work fine for *unsorted* lists. The OP is on the right track, but the solution has flaws.

Comment: Isn't this the same as `for(var i = 0; i < duplicateAuthors.length ; i++){
  uniqs[duplicateAuthors[i]] = null;
}   var uniqAuthors = Object.keys(uniqs);`

Comment: @Keon - Isn't this the same as - not clear with the statement?

Comment: @nikhil sorry about that fixed the comment

Comment: @Keon - The code shared in comment seems to work as well.

Answer (score 1):

Since object keys have to be unique I realized that you could also do the following to isolate unique values.

```
var uniqs = {};
for(var i = 0; i < duplicateAuthors.length ; i++){
        uniqs[duplicateAuthors[i]] = null;
}
var uniqAuthors = Object.keys(uniqs);
```

Answer (score 0):

This will take advantage of the fact that it's already sorted.

```
var previous;
var current;
for(var i = 0; i < duplicateAuthors.length; i++){
    current = duplicateAuthors[i];
    if (current && current != previous) {
        uniqAuthors.push(current);
        previous = current;
    }
}
```